# Mongoose: How can i sort the result list when i using update function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

the code like that:

```
Task.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: req.params.task_id}, updateObj, {new: true}, function (err, updatedTasks) {
        if (err) {
            return resultCode.serverError(req, res)
        }
        resultCode.success(req, res, updatedTasks);
    });
```

I want to sort the list 'updateTasks' by the field 'create_at', how can i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sorting](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort) in Mongoose has evolved over the releases. As of the **4.7.x** release of Mongoose, a descending sort on the date field can be done in any of the following ways:

```
Task.findByIdAndUpdate({ ... }).sort('-create_at').exec(function(err, updatedTasks) { ... });
Task.findByIdAndUpdate({ ... }).sort({create_at: -1}).exec(function(err, updatedTasks) { ... });
Task.findByIdAndUpdate({ ... }).sort({create_at: 'desc'}).exec(function(err, updatedTasks) { ... });
Task.findByIdAndUpdate({ ... }).sort({create_at: 'descending'}).exec(function(err, updatedTasks) { ... });
Task.findByIdAndUpdate({ ... }).sort([['create_at', -1]]).exec(function(err, updatedTasks) { ... });
```

For an ascending sort, omit the `-` prefix on the string version or use values of `1`, `asc`, or `ascending`.